# ARM assembly pointers to pointers?

Tags: c, pointers, assembly, arm

Suppose I am given as input to a function `foo` some pointer `*pL` that points to a pointer to a struct that has a pointer field next in it. I know this is weird, but all I want to implement in assembly is the line of code with the ** around it:

```
typedef struct CELL *LIST;
struct CELL {
  int element;
  LIST next;
};
void foo(LIST *pL){
**(*pL)->next = NULL;**

}
```

How do I implement this in ARM assembly? The issue comes from having nested startements when I want to store such as:

```
    .irrelevant header junk
foo:
    MOV R1, #0
    STR R1, [[R0,#0],#4]  @This is gibberish, but [R0,#0] is to dereference and the #4 is to offeset that.
```

Comment: This is assembly language. You have to break it down into smaller steps.

Comment: You have the address of a thing. From that thing, you can load the address of a different thing. Do that, and you have the address of a thing... For _n_ levels of pointers, it's no more difficult than repeating the same basic operation _n_ times until you have the address you care about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct sequence would be (assuming ARM ABI and `LIST *pL` is in R0),

```
.global foo
foo:
     ldr r0, [r0]      # get *pL to R0
     mov r1, #0        # set R1 to zero.
     str r1, [r0, #4]  # set (*pL)->List = NULL;
     bx  lr            # return
```

You can swap the first two assembler statements, but it is generally better to interleave ALU with load/store for performance.  With the ARM ABI, you can use R0-R3 without saving. `foo()` above should be callable from 'C' with most ARM compilers.

The 'C' might be simplified to,

```
void foo(struct CELL **pL)
{
   (*pL)->next = NULL;
}
```

if I understand correctly.

Comment: Shouldn't that comment in the assembly example be (*pL)->next = NULL (instead of (*pL)->List) ?

Comment: Yes, it was put there to see if anyone was paying attention :)

Answer (score 3):

The sequence would be similar to:

```
        ...                 ; r0 = LIST *pL = CELL **ppC (ptr2ptr2cell)
        ldr     r0,[r0]     ; r0 = CELL *pC (ptr2cell)
        mov     r1,#0       ; r1 = NULL
        str     r1,[r0,#4]  ; (*pL)->next = pC->next = (*pC).next = NULL
```

Comment: What is `ptr2ptr2node` meant to be? An address?

Comment: @psmears - I updated answer, assuming r0 starts off as CELL **, which I called ptr2ptr2cell for the example code. My example is now essentially the same as artless noise's answer.